# Email regex with - character

Tags: c#, regex, email

I use this regex for checking email. `/^\w+([-+.'']\w+)*@\w*([-.çöişğü]\w*)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/`
But this regex not accept email like `e-e--@hotmail.com`. Could u help me how to change my regex for accepting like this email?

Comment: Why the special case for the Turkish characters `çöişğü`?  Either you want to support full IDNA or you stick to strictly ASCII / punycode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change second `\w+` to `\w*`:

```
^\w+([-+.'']\w*)*@\w*([-.çöişğü]\w*)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tagged your question with `c#` tag why don't you use build-in [`System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx) class constructor for email validation? It supports a lot of mail address formats, and covers a bit more scenarios than your regular expression. See:

```
var isEmailValid = false;
try
{
    var email = new MailAddress("e-e--@hotmail.com");
    isValidEmail = true;
{
catch (FormatException x)
{
    // invalid email address
}
```

Isn't it easier than your regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in HTML5 pattern 
Email Pattern:

```
^(?:[-+~=!#$%&'*/?\^`{|}\w]+)(?:\.[-+~=!#$%&'*/?\^`{|}\w]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\w+([-+.'']*\w*)*@\w*([-.çöişğü]\w*)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex that I use specifcally for email validation, however I would not recomened this way, particularly when using in a buisness context; due to that fact that when thinking about email validation regular expressions are too strict. They do not allow room for domains of which are complelty possible, and to inlcude all of these possibilities would neeed a regex far to long, making it unstable.

```
  string strRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
        @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

    Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
    if (re.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text) || txtEmail.Text == "" || txtEmail.Text.Length > 100 && txtEmail.Text.Length < 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks");

    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address");



    }

}
```

This is  solotuion I would suggest which is more stable and efficent and utiliseszsthe **EmailAddressAttribute** as it is a built in class and allows mroe room and is not as strict as regex. hope this helps.

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtEmail_KeyDown);
        // Run Checks after the enter is pressed.
        if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode == (Keys.Tab))
        {
            if (!new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(txtEmail.Text))
            {

                MessageBox.Show(txtEmail.ToString() + " is not a valid Email address");
                txtEmail.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The address: " + txtEmail + " is valid");
                txtEmail.Clear();
            }
        }
```